# Use base class Copy CTOR in derived class

Tags: c++, oop

I know there are many posts on the subject, but I couldn't find any to fully answer my questions.

Say I have a Base class and a Derived class, which I implemented a CCtor and an assignment operator for it, something like the following:

```
class Base {
    char * name;
    ....
    Base(const Base& other) :name(nullptr) { *this = other }
    void operator=(const Base& other) { ... Deep copy of name } 
}


class Derived : public Base {
.... 
    Derived(const Derived& other) { *this = other ; }
    void operator=(const Derived& other) {
        Base::operator=(other);
        .....
    }
```

Now I have some questions about this design.

1. Is this the right design for the situation?
2. If i have a third class, between the base and the derived class, but it only contains primitive types, where shoud I copy them ? E.G. use the default assignment operator of the second class ? build a new one? only copy them on the third level ?
3. I could similary call the base class CCtor inside the derived class CCtor, instead of the assignment operator. What's the difference? If I place them in both methods will it try to copy the values two times?

Edit: Just to clarify, the design is what I was given in my project .. I have pointers so I have to use a deep copy .

Comment: Personally I would shoot for not having to write any copy constructor or copy assignment operator.  If you can write the class in a way where the default works then you don't have to worry about anything.  This is called the [rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this the right design for the situation?

No, not usually. The more idiomatic approach is to stop manually managing memory like `char* name` and use `std::string` or another type that does the right thing:

```
Class Base {
    std::string name;
    ....
    Base(const Base& other) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base& other) = default;
};
```

(Note that assignment operators should return a reference to the class, not `void`).

Or encapsulate the memory management in a class design specifically for that purpose (but `std::string` already is that type).

If you really *really* need to do it the dumb error-prone way, then implement your copy constructor to do copying:

```
    Base(const Base& other) { / * deep copy of name */ }
```

Then implement assignment as copy-and-swap:

```
    Base& operator=(const Base& other)
    {
      Base tmp(other);
      this->swap(tmp);
      return *this;
    }
```

This means you need a cheap, non-throwing `swap(Base&)` member function.

In any case the derived type copy constructor is just silly. You have a correct copy constructor for the base class so it should be:

```
Derived(const Derived& other) : Base(other) { }
```

And the assignment can use the base assignment:

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived& other)
{
   Base::operator=(other);
   return *this;
}
```

But writing these manually is unnecessary, you can just default its copy operations which will Do The Right Thing anyway:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived& ) = default;
```

> If i have a third class, between the base and the derived class, but it only contains primitive types, where shoud I copy them ? E.G. use the default assignment operator of the second class ? build a new one? only copy them on the third level ?

You should define the copy constructor and assignment operator of that class using `= default` as well. Once you've made `Base` safe to copy with correct behaviour, composing other classes to use it is trivial. The default behaviour will Do The Right Thing. You only need to define those operations manually if you need special treatment for something like dynamically-allocated memory that isn't being correctly managed by an RAII type.

> I could similary call the base class CCtor inside the derived class CCtor, instead of the assignment operator. What's the difference?

If you want to copy construct then use the copy constructor, not assignment. Use the right function for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have another one, In the situation I have another class between the base and the derived one, which include only primitive data members, should I explicitly call the second class CCtor ? Or how do I copy all its data members too ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover the other parts of your question

Comment: So basically you're saying that if I use the default CCtor and assignment operator , and the Base class is correctly defined, then the second class will also copy the Base class info ? So in my third class, CCtor\operator  , do I need to call the second class one's ?

Comment: The default implementation of special member functions (such as copy constructors and copy assignment operators) correctly copies the base classes and members. The compiler understands C++ better than you do and so will do the right thing. So make your base class work correctly, and let the derived classes rely on that.